# Permission issue on Yosemite server

Tags: macos, permission, osx-server

I have an old Mid 2010 Mac Pro running Yosemite that I am using as a server, and have a shared folder that should be accessible by anyone on the network.  Well, it's accessible, all right...but any file put there can only be opened by the user that put it there.  This is the exact opposite of what I'm looking for with this shared folder.  Is there any way to set the permissions such that anyone with access to the folder has read/write permissions for everything in the folder?

I tried to create a test document on one of my other machines (a Windows 10 Pro desktop) and put it in the shared folder.  This is the error I got when I tried to open the file, logged in as the server administrator.

[image: This is what happens when I try to open a file]

EDIT: I was asked to put terminal readouts of the permissions for the shared folder as well as its contents.  So, here they are:

Shared folder:

```
drwxrwxrwx+  6 admin  wheel  -           204 Aug 16 08:29 Share
0: user:_spotlight inherited allow list,search,file_inherit,directory_inherit
1: user:user1 allow list,add_file,search,add_subdirectory,delete_child,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity,file_inherit,directory_inherit
```

Contents (test.txt does not work; the two folders do work and are provided for comparison):

```
drwxrwxrwx+  6 admin  wheel  -       204 Aug 16 08:29 .
0: user:_spotlight inherited allow list,search,file_inherit,directory_inherit
1: user:user1 allow list,add_file,search,add_subdirectory,delete_child,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity,file_inherit,directory_inherit
drwxr-xr-x  33 root   wheel  -      1190 Aug 16 08:24 ..
-rw-r--r--@  1 user1  wheel  -      8196 Mar 20 16:18 .DS_Store
com.apple.FinderInfo      32 
0: user:_spotlight inherited allow read,execute
1: user:user1 inherited allow read,write,execute,append,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity
drwxr-xr-x+  6 admin  wheel  -       204 Jun 24 18:40 Backups
0: user:_spotlight inherited allow list,search,file_inherit,directory_inherit
1: user:user1 inherited allow list,add_file,search,add_subdirectory,delete_child,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity,file_inherit,directory_inherit
drwxrwxrwx+ 27 user1  wheel  nodump  918 Jun  9 15:04 Videos
0: user:_spotlight inherited allow list,search,file_inherit,directory_inherit
1: user:user1 inherited allow list,add_file,search,add_subdirectory,delete_child,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity,file_inherit,directory_inherit
-rw-------+  1 user1  wheel  nodump   20 Aug 16 08:03 test.txt
0: user:_spotlight inherited allow read,execute
1: user:user1 inherited allow read,write,execute,append,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity
```

Comment: Done.  Hopefully this helps.

Comment: I just got your modification; apparently I was using the wrong terminology.  I apologize for that.

Comment: How would I go about fixing it then?

Comment: Just tried that; it didn't work.  Still got the same error.

Comment: `sudo chmod -R +a "everyone allow list,add_file,search‌​,add_subdirectory,del‌​ete_child,readattr,wr‌​iteattr,readextattr,w‌​riteextattr,readsecur‌​ity,file_inherit,dire‌​ctory_inherit" /Volumes/vol_name/Sh‌​are` worked!  Thanks!  It's too bad that it was in a comment instead of an answer, because you deserve the rep for an accepted answer there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is related to accessing the share with a Windows client via SMB. It doesn't happen accessing it with an OS X client via SMB or AFP.

To quickly solve your problem remove all user1 ACLs with

```
sudo chmod -R -a "user1 allow list,add_file,search‌​,add_subdirectory,del‌​ete_child,readattr,wr‌​iteattr,readextattr,w‌​riteextattr,readsecur‌​ity,file_inherit,dire‌​ctory_inherit" /Volumes/vol_name/Sh‌​are
```

Replace vol_name by the proper volume name. If "Share" is the volume name omit the part "/vol_name"

Then add:

```
sudo chmod +a "everyone allow list,add_file,search‌​,add_subdirectory,del‌​ete_child,readattr,wr‌​iteattr,readextattr,w‌​riteextattr,readsecur‌​ity,file_inherit,dire‌​ctory_inherit" /Volumes/vol_name/Sh‌​are
```

You may then modify all stubborn subsequent files' and folders' permissions with:

```
sudo chmod ...
```

---

This is no nice solution and I will further inspect the access problem for Windows clients.